# How to measure the vertical space that was typeset without placing it into an environment?

Tags: spacing, floats, wrap, pandoc

I would like to achieve automatic clearing of a `{floatingfigure}` at the beginning of a new `\section` for texts automatically created by [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html). For this to work, I am in need of a way to measure the vertical space that was typeset by LaTeX since placing the `{floatingfigure}`.

I tried out the `placeins` package to no effect.

The ideal solution would involve placing a starting marker. An environment or any other block/braced/bracketed structure should not be used as the text that follows the `{floatingfigure}` is generally unknown. Everything needs to be implemented by renewing commands and environments in the preamble.

Should a second starting marker follow upon a first starting marker without taking a measurement, than the vertical measurement should be reset to 0pt.

Here is a minimum working example. I have placed comments from where to where I would like to measure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\imgheight

\usepackage{floatflt}
\renewenvironment{description}{%
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\vspace{-1ex}\Oldincludegraphics[width=4cm]{##1}}
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{
        \settototalheight\imgheight{##1}%
        \global\imgheight=\imgheight%
        ##1%
        \end{floatingfigure}%
        % I would like to measure vertical space from here...
        }%
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \begin{floatingfigure}[l]{4cm}}%
    {}
% end preamble.tex

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-a}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

% ... to here.
\vspace{\dimexpr\imgheight-3\baselineskip}
\section{Section title}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-b}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

In below document, the first paragraph is too short to wrap completely around `floatingfigure` **A**. Hence, I would like to achieve automatic `floatingfigure` clearing at the beginning of a new section or a new `floatingfigure`. Right now, I have done it manually by adding `\vspace{\dimexpr\imgheight-3\baselineskip}`.
[image: Section clearing that I would like to automate]

Comment: The length `\pagetotal` measures the distance from the baseline of the first line of the page. Probably you can play with it for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution based on `\pagetotal`, thanks to the comment of @karlkoeller.
In below example, automatic clearing of a wrapped `floatingfigure` is achieved both at the beginning of a new `floatingfigure` or a `\section`.

This is also a solution to the question: [How do I clear a floatfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67034/how-do-i-clear-a-floatfig)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% begin preamble.tex   
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\vimgflt
\newlength\vposflt
\newlength\vtypesetflt
\newlength\vspaceflt

\usepackage{floatflt}
\renewenvironment{description}{%
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\vspace{-1ex}\Oldincludegraphics[width=4cm]{##1}}
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{
        \settototalheight\vimgflt{##1}%
        \global\vimgflt=\vimgflt%
        ##1%
        \end{floatingfigure}%
        \setlength\vposflt\pagetotal%
        \global\vposflt=\vposflt%
        }%
    \clearflt
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \begin{floatingfigure}[l]{4cm}}%
    {}

\newcommand{\clearflt}{
    \par
    \setlength\vtypesetflt{\dimexpr\pagetotal-\vposflt}
    \ifdim \vtypesetflt<\vimgflt \setlength\vspaceflt{\dimexpr\vimgflt-\vtypesetflt+\baselineskip} \else \setlength\vspaceflt{0pt} \fi
    \vspace{\vspaceflt}
    }

\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\clearflt\Oldsection}
% end preamble.tex

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-a}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-b}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\section{Section title}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-c}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: automatic clearing of floatingfigure]

Comment: This solution still has an issue with page breaks. I am working on it.

Comment: The solution is not compatible (yet?) with `\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}` in the preamble.

Comment: Happy that my comment leads you to a (almost) working solution!

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks. A follow-up question dealing with page breaks was posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130673/how-to-circumvent-a-late-pagetotal-reset-to-0pt).

Comment: @karlkoeller ...and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130679/is-there-an-alternative-for-usepackagenobottomtitlestitlesec) is a follow-up question about `titlesec`