# ConTeXt: Figure scaling to width and text wrapping for Pandoc-generated documents

Tags: graphics, context, context-mkiv, wrap, pandoc

Consider the following [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)-generated [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/) document:

```
\setuppapersize [A4][A4]
\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1.5in, cutspace=1.5in,
                 height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]

\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
  location=global,
  wfactor=fit,
  ]

\definedescription
  [description]
  [headstyle=bold, style=normal, location=hanging, width=4cm]

\starttext
\placefigure[here,nonumber]{Little kitten}{\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/480/300][method=jpg]}

\startdescription{{\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/640/400][method=jpg]}}
  \input bryson
\stopdescription
\stoptext
```

[image: current output]

### Question

Little kitten should grow to `\textwidth`. The other kitten should fit through a width of 4cm with text wrapped around it. Its picture should be flush at the top with the wrapped text.

The kittens may not be touched; only the setup before `\starttext` may be changed. Furthermore, no references to the image URLs should appear in the preamble for this problem to be solved as generally as possible.

I tried something with `\setupexternalfigures` and `wfactor=fit` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: With your input and a recent context I get exactly the result you describe and not what your screenshots show. Maybe updating your context version already solves the problem.

Comment: @Marco `context --version` yields `ConTeXt Process Management 0.52` and `current version: 2012.05.30 11:26`. I will test on a [SolydX](http://solydxk.com/products/solydx/) machine later on and report back here. This rolling Debian Testing release should have a more recent version of ConTeXt in its repositories.

Comment: Instead of using the distros repository I'd suggest to install [ConTeXt standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone). It can be installed as a regular user, no admin rights required, and it's the most up-to-date version.

Comment: @Marco Are you using the beta or current stable version?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: In terms of ConTeXt development speed, `2012.05.30` is a stoneage distribution. I normally install ConTeXt beta.

Comment: BTW, setting the image as the description title is a sneaky way of wrapping text around an image. Are you generating only tex/pdf output or do you also care about other formats? In the former case, have a look at the [filter](https://github.com/adityam/filter) module; in the latter case, consider using a [preprocessor](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/) to be able to extend markdown.

Comment: @Aditya It is the latter case; I also care about HTML output. The "sneaky" trick is a classic CSS trick of [Dan Cederholm's *Bullet Proof Web Design*](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1815998&seqNum=4). I had read your preprocessor post before with much interest. However, I first would like to try and see if I can do without. ConTeXt promises separation of style from content, so I gather this should not pose any problem?

Comment: Currently, Debian Testing also offers only `version: 2012.05.30 11:26`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

With `version: 2012.05.30 11:26` of ConTeXt, `\setupexternalfigures[wfactor=fit]` has no effect. Hence, the following solution which also *keeps in-line figures intact.*

This is all really nice, because [LaTeX2e has not be found capable (yet) of pulling off a similar feat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130507/26348). In contrast to ConTeXt, [float clearing is not automatic in LaTeX2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130665/26348); instead, one needs to fuddle around with distance measurements.

```
\setuppapersize [A4][A4]
\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1.5in, cutspace=1.5in,
                 height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]

\setuptolerance[horizontal, tolerant, stretch]

% Keep old definitions
\let\oldplacefigure\placefigure
\let\oldexternalfigure\externalfigure

% For full text-width figures
\def\placefigure[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\externalfigure[##1]{\oldexternalfigure[##1][method=jpg, wfactor=fit]}%
  \oldplacefigure[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \let\externalfigure\oldexternalfigure% Reset for in-line figures
  }

% For figures with wrapped text
\definedescription[description][
  headstyle=bold,
  style=normal,
  location=hanging,
  width=4cm
  ]

\def\startdescription#1{%
  \def\externalfigure[##1]{\oldexternalfigure[##1][method=jpg, width=4cm]}%
  \oldplacefigure[none,left,high]{}{#1}%
  \let\externalfigure\oldexternalfigure% Reset for in-line figures
  }
\def\stopdescription{\endgraf}

\starttext
  \placefigure[here,nonumber]{Little kitten}{\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/480/300]}

  \startdescription{{\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/640/400]}}
    \input bryson
  \stopdescription
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

### Caveat

The cats have a caveat though; When the figure with the description occurs near the end of a page, its wrapped text will fall off the page like in the following example. I distilled a minimum working example out of it and linked it as [a follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133043/26348).

[image: caveat]

### Newer ConTeXt versions

Eventually, I found [how to install ConTeXt Standalone under Debian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132464/26348). I can confirm that `\setupexternalfigures[wfactor=fit]` is now functional in ConTeXt `version: 2013.09.09 19:45`. This can significantly reduce the code when, like in the example above, no in-line images are used. However, when in a more general case in-line images are present, `[wfactor=fit]` cannot be used because it acts also upon these. `[wfactor=fit]` acting upon in-line images could be considered a ConTeXt bug. Therefore, above solution which also works with older ConTeXt versions, remains the more general solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that in the newer version, you will need to use `alternative=...` instead of `location=...` for the description environment.

Answer (score 1):

Really, you are using the wrong (ConTeXt) markup to achieve the affect. However, I'll provide a solution that answers your question (without answering your question :)

The requirement stated:

> only the setup before \starttext may be changed.

So, here it goes:

```
\setuppapersize [A4][A4]
\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1.5in, cutspace=1.5in,
                 height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]

\setupexternalfigures
  [
    order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
    location=global,
    wfactor=fit,
  ]

\definedescription
  [description]
  [headstyle=bold, style=normal, alternative=hanging, width=4cm]

\definefloat[hangingfigure]
            [hangingfigures]
            [figures]

\setupfloat [hangingfigure]
            [
              default={left,none},
            ]

\def\startdescription{\placehangingfigure\empty}
\def\stopdescription{\endgraf}

\useexternalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/640/400]
                  [http://placekitten.com/g/640/400]
                  [method=jpg,width=4cm]

\starttext
    \placefigure[here,nonumber]{Little kitten}{\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/480/300][method=jpg]}

  \startdescription{{\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/640/400][method=jpg]}}
    \input bryson
  \stopdescription
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

More seriously, markdown provides too few markup options to achieve complicated elements. My own solution is to use a preprocessor to give it a boost, but YMMW.

Comment: In my 2012.05.30 version of ConTeXt, the above code produces an error on line 37, as you can see for yourself by pasting the code to [live.contextgarden.net](http://live.contextgarden.net/). Also, the "hard" URL links in `\useexternalfigure` do not make this a generally applicable solution that can be used with Pandoc-generated documents. I will add this requirement to the question. I would like to try this out with a newer ConTeXt version, but I am experiencing problems with the installation under Debian. This does not take away that I very much appreciate your answer.

Comment: I know that using `\useexternalfigure` makes this solution useless in the generic case, and that is why I said that it really doesn't answer your question. Newer version of pandoc allows you to write your own writer using `lua` (though I have not tried it). Using that you may be able to translate pandoc code into something that is easier to tweak at ConTeXt end.

Comment: For the error with old version of ConTeXt, use the following definition instead: 
`\def\startdescription#1{\placefigure[left,none]{}{#1}}`

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the error. However, little kitten is still small over here. I was also wondering whether a `\def\externalfigure` redefinition within the `\def\startdescription` definition were possible to eliminate the hard URL-linking.

Comment: Rather than redefining externalfigures, you could try `\setupextranlfigure[width=4cm]` inside the definition of `\startdescription`.