# ConTeXt Standalone installation problem under Debian GNU/Linux

Tags: installing, context, context-mkiv, standalone, debian

I am trying to install ConTexT Standalone under [LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php), a Debian GNU/Linux operating system.
I followed the [system-wide installation instructions](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#System-wide_installation) step-by-step without any problem.
Except for the final step, executing `. /opt/context/tex/setuptex`, which fails in error:

```
bash: dirs: +P: invalid number
dirs: usage: dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]
"" is not a valid TEXROOT path.
(There is no file "/texmf/tex/plain/base/plain.tex")
provide a proper tex root (like '. setuptex /something/tex')
```

I also tried with adding the line:

`export PATH="$PATH:/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin"` at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` to no avail.
Surely, somebody over here must have ample experience with installing ConTeXt Standalone under Debian...

Comment: I've never seen that error. Does it also occur when you simply run `wget http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/first-setup.sh && chmod +x first-setup.sh && ./first-setup.sh && . tex/setuptex`

Comment: @Marco I receive exactly the same error. It looks like `setuptex` is searching in vain for `/texmf/tex/plain/base/plain.tex`.

Comment: i was going to comment but requires fifty plus reputation. i tried the same and unfortunately it did not work. although the errors on my system were different than yours, it required other files that i didn't have available. my suggestion, and perhaps this is not what you want, is to install texlive and add <code> PATH=/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin/i386-linux:PATH$ </code> to the bashrc file.

Comment: Issuing `find . -name plain.tex` in `/opt/context` gives
`./tex/texmf/tex/plain/base/plain.tex`

Comment: The error message shows a wrong path. It should look for `/opt/context/tex/texmf/tex/plain/base/plain.tex` instead of `/texmf/tex/plain/base/plain.tex`. Try `. tex/setuptex tex`. Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Marco I tried `. tex/setuptex tex` and the like before; it does not help. I am using `bash`. Where would the `TEXROOT` path be defined?

Comment: TEXROOT is defined in `setuptex` and usually determined automatically or constructed from the optional argument. What does `. tex/setuptex tex` output (you can update your question)? And what does `context --version` output after setting the path manually on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem. I had to adopt and adapt an excerpt of the [ConTeXt Standalone instructions for Ubuntu](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Ubuntu#With_ConTeXt_Standalone_.E2.80.93_should_work_with_all_Ubuntu_versions). This is a bit weird, since [LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) is not based on Ubuntu at all. Conversely, Ubuntu sure is derived from Debian.

Here is the complete recipe:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/context
sudo chown $USER -R /opt/context
cd /opt/context
rsync -av rsync://contextgarden.net/minimals/setup/first-setup.sh .
sh ./first-setup.sh

sudo mkdir /var/cache/context
sudo mkdir /var/cache/context/texmf-cache
sudo chmod 777 /var/cache/context/texmf-cache
nano ./tex/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua
```

Change the value of `TEXMFCACHE` from `"$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-cache"` to `"/var/cache/context/texmf-cache"`, save and close.

So far, this was all pretty standard procedure. Now comes the Debian-specific bit.

Open the following file in your favourite editor:
`sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc`

At the end of this file, add the following lines *in this specific order:*

```
export OSFONTDIR=~/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts
export TEXROOT=/opt/context/tex
export PATH="/opt/context/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin:/opt/context/bin:$PATH"
```

*Leave out the "-64" if you are using a 32-bit system.*
Save and close, then issue the following commands at the prompt:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
sh ./first-setup.sh --modules=all
```

Check with `context --version`

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.60
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2013.09.09 19:45
```

Comment: You are now using `source <filename>` instead of `. <filename>`. I don't really know the difference between the two, but I typically use `source <..>` instead of `. <...>`.

Comment: @Aditya The dot is specified by POSIX and the most portable way of sourcing a file in any shell. Some shells (e.g. bash and zsh) implement the `source` command which does the same as the dot. I typically use `. <…>` instead of `source <…>`.